# Creating multiple objects at once with nested loops in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `batch_create` method in my AssignmentsController that allows Assigners to assign Assignments to multiple students at a time. This saves an `assignment_id` into the queue field of each student. `assignment_id` gets serialized as JSON and stored as an array in the queue field for each student.

My issue is that currently when using `batch_create` to mass assign assignments, students end up with the same assignment_ids in their queues. I need to assign only 1 assignment_id to each student's queue per batch_create method, not all assignment_ids.

Assignments are essentially instances of Activities generated by the AssignmentsController.

An example run of batch_create to assign 1 activity to two students at the same time would produce the following two assignment_ids: 2316 and 2317.

In the two student's queue fields, the result would include both 2316 and 2317 for both users. I want 2316 to be in one user's queue and 2317 to be in the other user's queue, not both.

```
# app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb

  def batch_create
    # Make sure current user (teacher) is assigner if not set by admin.
    if params[:assignment][:assigner_id].present?
      assigner_id = params[:assignment][:assigner_id]
    else
      assigner_id = current_user.id
    end

    activities = params[:assignment][:activity_ids].nil? ? []
                  : params[:assignment][:activity_ids].split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }

    students = params[:assignment][:student_ids].nil? ? []
                  : params[:assignment][:student_ids].split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }

    assignments = []
    activities.each do |activity_id|
      students.each do |student_id|
        assignments << {
          activity_id: activity_id,
          assignee_id: student_id
        }
      end
    end

    @assignments = Assignment.create(assignments) do |a|
      a.assigner_id = assigner_id
      a.assessment = params[:assignment][:assessment]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @assignments.present?
        # Add assignment(s) to the student's queue
        @assignments.each do |assignment|
          students.each do |student_id|
            @student = User.find(student_id)
            @student.queue_will_change!
            @student.queue << assignment.id
            @student.save!
          end
        end

        format.html { redirect_to assignments_path, notice: 'Assignments were successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: That controller needs to go on a **serious** diet.

Comment: @jvillian hey thanks, do you mind pointing out what things I can do to slim it down or that I should avoid?

Comment: Sure, post it as a separate question and I'd be happy to offer thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just grabbing the User uniquely by modifying one line in that block:

```
# Add assignment(s) to the student's queue
@assignments.each do |assignment|
    @student = User.find(assignment.assignee_id)
    @student.queue_will_change!
    @student.queue << assignment.id
    @student.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
@assignments.each do |assignment|
  students.each do |student_id|
    @student = User.find(student_id)
    @student.queue_will_change!
    @student.queue << assignment.id unless @student.queue.include? assignment.id
    @student.save!
  end
end
```

That should do it.

Comment: Assignments are still being saved to all student queues with this method.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry, its actually doing the same thing. Let me figure it out.